# Two Listdensityplot figures : Use one of them as a mask for the other one

Tags: plotting

I successfully plot two listdensityplot of thermical values distribution on an object. I want to use ne of them as a mask (to remove the backrgound) on the other one.

My question is : How to do this ?

Is it possible to modify the colormap (as using the alpha parameter of the image considering RVBAlpha of opencv in python ?)

Does anybody know as to overimposed two ListDensityPlot? On the other hand
there is a mode to make transparency as option for graphics object in
Mathematica?

I hope that my question is quite clear and, in advance, thank you for your support !

Comment: Can you give an example of code that produces two such plots so that we have something to work with?

Comment: @C.E. here an example (I have 2 listdensityplot) : 
<pre><code>
ListDensityPlot[data[[1]], PlotRange -> {{3 - 7.5, 11 - 7.5}, {-4, 8}, All}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], Frame -> False, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold], LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 30, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], AxesStyle -> Directive[30, Bold], FrameStyle -> Directive[30, Bold], ImageSize -> 600, AxesStyle -> Bold, AspectRatio -> 1/(8/14.75), ImageSize -> 300] 
<pre><code>
Thank you !

Comment: Hi deezer, I am new but it's very hard to analyze your problem unless you provide sample data and maybe attach a sample picture of what you want to do. You have an option to edit your question. best

Comment: @Rupesh, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Rupesh, I have two figures plot with listdensitypot. I want to use one of the 2 as a alpha channel to the other figure to set as the background as presented here :

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/1Zh5NQZ/ldp.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `Regionfunction` or `Piecewise`.  You can divide your data into parts and plot for a given region. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77545/listdensityplot-and-regionfunction

Comment: @Rupesh, Thank you, I tried your method. 
How is it possible to use Regionfunction with raw values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach would be to work directly with input data as in Rupesh's answer.

You can also process the two images produced by `ListDensityPlot` using [`ImageAdd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdd.html) or using  a combination of [`ImageMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMultiply.html) and [`RemoveBackground`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveBackground.html).

```
data1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1];

SeedRandom[777]
data2 = RandomInteger[1, {6, 6}];
```

Use `ListDensityPlot`  to get a plots without a frame and no paddings:

```
ldpa = ListDensityPlot[data1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];

ldpb = ListDensityPlot[data2, DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
```

Separate the plots and the legends:

```
{ldp1, legend1} = {ldpa[[1]], ldpa[[2, 1]]};
{ldp2, legend2} = {ldpb[[1]], ldpb[[2, 1]]};


Row[{ldp1, ldp2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Binarize `ldp2` to use it as mask:

```
mask = Binarize @ ldp2;
```

Use `ImageAdd[ldp1, mask]` or `RemoveBackground[ImageMultiply[ldp1, mask], Black]` to get the masked version of `ldp1`:

```
Grid[{{"", #2}, {#, #3}} & @@ (Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ 
   {ldp1, mask, ImageAdd[ldp1, mask]}), 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Use `ColorNegate @ mask` instead of `mask` to get:

```
Grid[{{"", #2}, {#, #3}} & @@ (Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ 
     {ldp1, ColorNegate @ mask, ImageAdd[ldp1, ColorNegate @ mask]}), 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:** Adding frame, ticks and labels and show with the legend:

```
ClearAll[modifyDataRange]
modifyDataRange[drange_] :=  Graphics[Show[#][[1]] /. 
     Raster[a_, _, b___] :> Raster[a, drange, b]] &;

plotrange = Transpose[PlotRange[ldp1]];

labels = {"LDP1", "MASK", "masked LDP1"};

Grid[{{legend1, #2}, {#, #3}} & @@ 
  MapThread[Show[#, PlotLabel -> #2, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> Automatic, 
     PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], ImageSize -> Medium] &, 
 {{ldp1,  modifyDataRange[plotrange]@mask, 
     modifyDataRange[plotrange]@ImageAdd[ldp1, mask]}, labels}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Alternatively, show the legend next to the plots:

```
Grid[{{"", Legended[#2, legend2]}, 
    {Legended[#, legend1], Legended[#3, legend1]}} & @@ 
  MapThread[Show[#, PlotLabel -> #2, Frame -> True, 
      ImagePadding -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], 
      ImageSize -> Medium] &, 
   {{ldp1, ldp2, modifyDataRange[plotrange]@ImageAdd[ldp1, mask]}, labels}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer ! It is perfect. I have one more question :

- How to use the result in a ListDensityPlot to get the colorbar the axis number and title ...

Again, thank you !

Comment: @deezertsix, please see the update.

Comment: this is very great ! 
Just, the BarLegend seems not to be display. Do you have a trick ? 
Very Good job !

Comment: @deezertsix, added the legend.

Comment: Perfect ! Again, thank you both Rupesh and kglr for your kind answer !

Comment: a final question, haw can I plot directly the new listdensityplot without the Grid method ?

Comment: @deezertsix, use `Legended[Show[modifyDataRange[plotrange]@ImageAdd[ldp1, mask], 
  PlotLabel -> "masked LDP1", Frame -> True, 
  ImagePadding -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], 
  ImageSize -> Medium], legend1]`

Comment: perfect, thank you very much for your support !

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sample:

```
(*Raw data*)
data= Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1];
fig1 = ListDensityPlot[data,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 <= x <= 2 && y >= 1], 
       ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic];
```

Another way around is:

```
(*second Raw data*)
data1=Flatten[Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1];
```

I select a part of first first data: 
you can use `Select` or `ImplicitRegion` for it:

```
new=Select[data, 1 <= #[[1]] <= 2 && #[[2]]>=1 &];
ListDensityPlot[{data1, new}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic](*Plot*)
```

Let me know of any questions you have

Comment: Thank you for your code, but, I was not clear and my images were just example. I want to do something like that, but, I want to adjust the mask with the values of the raw data and not the position on the figure. In fact, I do not have lines and perpendicular corners but asymmetric shapes.